# Properly creating article sections

Tags: html, css

I'm creating an article column with a section for each article. I'm wondering how do i responsively add space between sections, at the moment if the text for the section is long, it can overlap my  `hr` tag and go onto my next section. This problem is only visible by if I look at it on mobile.

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/MyWoPX

I published to azure for a better view http://testingwebground.azurewebsites.net/ if I shrink the width as small as possible, it shows the image below

http://snag.gy/17mpD.jpg

```
<section>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="row-sm-height">
          <aside class="col-sm-6">
            <a>
            <img src="http://bandwagonbible.com/Stories/NFLBeginnersGuide/Image1.JPG" />
          </a>
          </aside>
          <aside class="col-sm-6">
            <div>
              <span> <a id="Article_Category">Football</a></span>
              <h2 id="Article_Header2">
                               Beginners Guide to Bandwagoning: The 4 Things You Need To Know About How the NFL Works
                            </h2> 
              <span id="Article_Date">November 12, 2015</span>                 
            </div>
          </aside>
        </div>
      </div>
      <hr>
</section>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is in your height definition on #Article_Header2

```
#Article_Header2 {
    height: 48px;
    font: normal normal normal normal 16px / normal 'Roboto Condensed', sans-serif;
    margin: 0px;
}
```

If you want to preserve the minimum height of 48px then maybe use **min-height** instead. Like this:

```
#Article_Header2 {
    min-height: 48px;
    font: normal normal normal normal 16px / normal 'Roboto Condensed', sans-serif;
    margin: 0px;
}
```

The thing I usually do when adding spaces between elements like yours is add **margin-top** to all elements (in your case articles), and remove the margin from the **:first-child**.

Comment: Hi Dsasko, it definitely fixed the overlap but I think that only needs to be applied to a a media query, may I ask what's the proper way to do it in a media query.

Comment: If you wish to separate the looks of the site on mobile/desktop then you would do it like this: @media (min-width: 960px){ .selector{ some:css; } } This would define styles of the desktop and the regular stypes (which you would define before the media query) would determine the mobile site. This approach is called mobile-first. The value of 960px is up to you to determine when you want the break to happen. I suggest you look up "media query" on MDN, they explained it in great detail.